App Store Connect Developer can't see my account
I have opened an Individual App Store Connect account, and I have created one app on it that is ready for submission (descriptions, screenshots, etc.) but without the code.
Now I have added  a Developer in User and Access, here he is:

He can log into the App Store Connect and see everything there, however, he can't see my account from the xCode and he can't deploy the code.
Also, I can't click on Additional Resources option.
Can someone please help me and tell me what to do?

You cannot add developers, since it is an individual account. You can add developers only to Organisation account. 
